# What is the object of the verb here?

Tags: verbs, ellipsis, objects

> He put the snacks on the table for us to savor.

Is the verb *savour* used transitively in the above sentence? Is this a case of ellipsis where the object *them (snacks)* is understood?

Comment: Yes, it's a transitive usage *...for us to savour [**the snacks**]*. I think ***to savour*** can *only* be a transitive verb. But you should be aware that ***to savour*** isn't very often used literally today, so your example text might well be interpreted as a *facetious* usage even if that wasn't your intention. You might be better switching to an alternative, such as ***enjoy, nibble on, eat,...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you very much. So it's used more figuratively then, right? Like _He passed on his nuggets of wisdom for us to savor._

Comment: I think you've got it, yeah. The example in your question is ***literal*** (snacks really are things to eat that are *literally* tasty!), but figuratively you could certainly savour "nuggets of wisdom" (a *particularly* apt metaphoric usage if the speaker knows of and likes to eat tasty [***chicken nuggets***](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/breaded_chicken_nuggets_35643), as opposed to drooling over the prospect of finding valuable ***gold nuggets**!* :)